# Lua math ceil round up number when there is no digits after decimal point

Tags: lua, ceil

I would like to round up the numbers by using math.ceil in Lua.

Some of the cases are make sense like:

- ceil(260.5) -> 261

But some of the cases are weird like:

- ceil(2.2*100) -> 221 # Suppose there is no round up and the answer is 220

I have no idea why it acts like this, what should I do if I would like to round up the number when there are digits after decimal point, and no rounding up if there is just an integer?

-- Update:
Thanks for the answering from @cyclaminist:
2.2 * 100 is actually a little larger than 220.0 because 2.2 can't be represented exactly as a floating point number. Try ('%.15f'):format(2.2 * 100): for me, it gives '220.000000000000028'

Ceil will return the integer which is the closest and not smaller than 220.000000000000028, so that 221 is returned.

The solution to get 220 is:
math.floor(2.2*100 + 0.5) -> return 220, Since math.floor return the closest but not larger than 220.000000000000028

Comment: `2.2 * 100` is actually a little larger than `220.0` because `2.2` can't be represented exactly as a floating point number. Try `('%.15f'):format(2.2 * 100)`: for me, it gives `'220.000000000000028'`.

Comment: @cyclaminist , got it, so that the ceil will take 221 as the closest integer for 2.2*100. Thank you for your answering!

Answer (score 1):

Try `tonumber(string.format("%.0f",2.2*100))`.

Comment: math.floor(2.2*100 + 0.5) can do it too! Thanks @lhf